# php unexpected conversion to int

Tags: php, simplexml

I have the following code excerpt

```
$sgn=$creditInvoice ? 1.0 : -1.0;
$net=$sgn*$s->totalNetValue;$vat=$sgn*$s->totalVatAmount;
 echo "net=$net vat=$vat s->totalNetValue=$s->totalNetValue s->totalVatAmount=$s->totalVatAmount gettype(s->totalNetValue)=".gettype($s->totalNetValue)."<br>";
```

The output is unexpectedly (to me)

> net=-28 vat=-6 s->totalNetValue=28.32 s->totalVatAmount=6.80
> gettype(s->totalNetValue)=object

The data has been read by simplexml_load_string so it has to do with that.
If a cast the $s->totalNetValue to float or double it works correctly.
What should I do to write "correct but not redundant code" ?

Bellow the complete code to reproduce:

```
<?php

$x='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <invoice> <invoiceSummary> <totalNetValue>20.12</totalNetValue> <totalVatAmount>4.83</totalVatAmount> </invoiceSummary> </invoice>';

$i = simplexml_load_string($x);

print_r($i);echo '<br>';

$s = $i->invoiceSummary;

print_r($s);echo '<br>';

$net=1.0*$s->totalNetValue;
$vat=1.0*$s->totalVatAmount;

echo "net=$net vat=$vat s->totalNetValue=$s->totalNetValue s->totalVatAmount=$s->totalVatAmount gettype(s->totalNetValue)=".gettype($s->totalNetValue)."<br>";

?>
```

Comment: Can you show the segment of the XML it's using.

Comment: So your code generally looks like [this](https://3v4l.org/f02ce)? If so, `simplexml_load_string` returns objects of type `SimpleXMLElement` which implements `__toString()` which is how the string concatenation works. The multiplication also uses that and because of type juggling rules it gets converted to an int.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Yes, that makes sense, but why do the type juggling rules turn it into a int when you multiply -1.0 by it?

Comment: Here we have a multiplication of a number with an object, if the __toString() is called and acts, it should return the string that should be converted to a number afterwards ( these are all mine suppositions as I am totally novel to php).

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis Just as an experiment you could try to remove the context by doing: `$net = $sgn * ($s->totalNetValue);`.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, in the case of `1.0` both values are actually treated as floats, it just happens that no decimal is present. https://3v4l.org/mk8p8

Comment: @ChrisHaas: This is unknown territory to me, but are you saying that, even though `1.0` is a float, the reason the decimal value is zero the multiplication returns an int? Sorry, I cannot wrap my brain around this.

Comment: The main problem we have here is that [the question doesn't contain a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis, when you multiply those values, `__toString` gets called on the object which results in `float * string`. Per [type juggling rules](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php), in a numeric context both are treated as a float. Later, when you perform string concatenation, there's no "memory" of the previous thing, it was an implicit cast at that exact moment in time, and calling `gettype` on it sees that it is still an object.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, no provided code is actually showing that an `int` exists at the type level. Instead we are seeing the output of an `echo` which will always be a `string`. Inside of that string is a `4` which looks like an int but could be a string or a float with no decimal place even. But multiplying a float with a string will result in an attempt at converting that string to a float and the final result will be a float. https://3v4l.org/mk8p8#v8.1.9

Comment: I have another idea. This seems unlikely, but perhaps the point in 28.32 isn't the normal dot. So when it needs to be a string you get 28.32, but when it needs to be converted to a float it stops at the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, coffee finally kicked in an I'm seeing what everyone else was seeing.

Prior to PHP 7.3, when SimpleXML objects were used in a mathematical context they were always treated as ints. This change is documented [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration73.incompatible.php#migration73.incompatible.simplexml).

And you can see the [old way here](https://3v4l.org/c8A7j#v7.2.34) and the [new way here](https://3v4l.org/c8A7j#v7.3.13)

Comment: Yes, that completely explains it. Nice. I want some of that coffee!

Comment: I just kept staring at things trying to figure out where the "int" stuff in the discussion was coming from and was apparently thinking way too abstract! Thanks for helping me think this through!